# Windows/.NET way to monitor/debug the serial port?

Tags: .net, windows, serial-port, lockup

I have an application which is .NET 2.0, running on Windows XP Professional.  This app uses the Serial Port to communicate with some custom devices.

For some reason, a few of our custom built PCs have an issue with the Serial Port, where it will stop functioning after a few weeks of use.  Other that auto-reboots, which won't work in my scenario, are there any utilities out there which can debug/diagnose the serial port?  Is there any .NET library which can help with this (can I write my own utility to debug the port)?

Also, has anyone had any experience with the following library:
[Sax CommStudio](http://www.sax.net/commstudio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Sax CommStudio in the past, but now I just use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.

By any chance are you using a USB serial port? I've had problems with those going BSOD and whatnot. If that's the case, you have a driver problem, not a software problem.

If you want to do some troubleshooting outside of your app, you might have a look at [HHD's serial monitor](http://www.hhdsoftware.com/Products/home/serial-monitor.html). I think they have a free trial, but if you're doing any serious RS232 development it's really worth buying.

Comment: Excellent answer, but we are using a normal serial port.

Answer (score 2):

portmon - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx

I'd say that's the closest to a 'standard' tool for monitoring serial ports on Windows.  But heaven help you if you need to try and track down something after two weeks using this kind of tool...

I would suspect a driver problem - is it a 'proper' serial port with a conventional UART, or is it some kind of USB-Serial converter or similar?

Update 2017:  Portmon was a reasonably useful suggestion in 2008, but has never been updated to work with 64-bit versions of Windows, so don't bother trying it now on a modern machine.

Comment: Agreed -- works pretty well for basic things but any large amount of data would probably be unmanageable.

Comment: portmon didn't work for me on Windows 7 64-bit and I've seen other reports of it not working on x64.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the HDD Software Free Serial Port Monitor.  It will log all the traffic and open/close on the serial port.  That way you have a log of the data and the operation of the serial port.

[Free Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/index.html)

Comment: Sometimes it hangs all computer. Today it happened to me three - four times in course of one hour.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you are running on Windows XP and .NET 2.0, .NET may well be your problem since there are bugs affecting serial ports in most versions of .NET. The minimum version that I'd recommend for using serial ports is .NET 3.5 SP1.

See also:
http://blog.zachsaw.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html